# Use mysql select query to display result of another select query

Tags: mysql

Hello i have the following select query that gives the output for 4 columns :

```
SELECT (C.customer_id) AS customer_id,
CONCAT((C.first_name),' ',(C.last_name))  Customername,
(CASE WHEN l.line_status=0 THEN '0' WHEN l.line_status ='1' THEN '1' END) STATUS,

,IF(l.`line_status` = '0', 'enabled', 'disabled') AS account_status
FROM 
agingdetails ad , customer c  , customers_cycletype cct , customer_contact cc , line l , customer_line_mapping clm
WHERE C.customer_id = ad.customerid     
AND cct.customer_id=C.customer_id  
AND cc.customer_id=C.customer_id
AND cct.cycle_type= 'A' 
AND c.customer_id=24
AND ad.customerid=clm.customer_id
AND clm.line_id = l.line_id
GROUP BY l.line_id
```

The result of above query is below for 1 single customer is :

```
customer_id    Customername       STATUS    account_status  
     24        ENDTEST5            1         disabled        
     24        ENDTEST5            0         enabled         
     24        ENDTEST5            0         enabled
```

The requirement is that if the STATUS column of this customer_id  displays as status '1' out of total 3 rows then it should show "disabled" in account_status column for other remaining rows also. something like below.

```
customer_id    Customername       STATUS    account_status  
    24        ENDTEST5            1         disabled        
    24        ENDTEST5            0         disabled         
    24        ENDTEST5            0         disabled
```

TIA to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
...
IF(SUM(l.`line_status`) OVER (PARTITION BY C.customer_id, C.first_name, C.last_name), 
   'enabled', 
   'disabled') AS account_status
...
```

Comment: Many Thanks for the quick response @akina . Somehow the the mysql version on client side is 5.7 due to which your solution is not working and giving error "Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OVER ( PARTITION BY C.customer_id, C.first_name, C.last_name), 
   'enabled', ". 
Is their any method through which we can achieve this. ?

Comment: @BaljotSingh *the mysql version on client side is 5.7* If so then use your query as subquery and `IF(MAX(STATUS),'disabled','enabled')` in outer query (with GROUP BY by another columns).